# Supported @SuppressWarnings Values in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

What are all of the supported values for `@SuppressWarnings` in Android Studio?

I couldn't find any documentation on it, and I know it isn't the same as Eclipse because "null" doesn't work. You can catch null warnings with "all", but as you can imagine I'd rather not.

Comment: These are not intended to be entered by hand, use `Alt`+`Enter`, **Suppress...** menu item (from the right arrow sub-menu) on the code that is highlighted with the inspection.

Comment: [`java.lang.SuppressWarnings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) suppresses "named compiler warnings" and every compiler / IDE / Android Lint (?) / .. can AFAIK have their own ones and should ignore the ones it does not know. So you may have to suppress more than one type if you don't want warnings in all environments.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows, Linux) or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (OS X), then either press <kbd>→</kbd> or click on the arrow pointing right at the end of "Replace with lambda...", finally select some of the **Suppress...** menu items available.

[image]

Comment: anyone know the key for OS X?

Comment: @seiterm it should be the same, see also [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/suppressing-inspections.html).

Comment: @HugoGresse It's under the "Convert to local" submenu.

Comment: @seiterm: Use Option+Enter

Comment: Let me emphasize the really important part of the answer **"from right arrow sub-menu"**. You basically have to click  `Alt`+`Enter` then `→` on a line with a small arrow. Then select **Suppress...** row.

Comment: Worth noting also that the alt+enter (opt/al + enter on Mac keyboards) will sometimes provide a solution to the warning so it's worth just doing this when resolving errors as a first option in case there are quick fixes.

Comment: "These are not intended to be entered by hand" ... that's subjective

Comment: In Android Studio 2.3, for warnings such as `Statement with empty body`, the menu item with the `→` is called **`Inspection 'Statement with empty body' options`**. For `Unused declaration`s, the menu item is called **`Safe delete 'foo'`** for fields, or **`Safe delete 'bar()'`** for methods.

Comment: Unfortunately the arrow button is not selectable by mouse. You have to use the right arrow key

Answer (score 13):

Look at this page for list of `@SuppressWarnings` :

https://gist.github.com/elevenetc/bf795f94aaf3e92169ef

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to suppress "function never used" warnings and none of the @SuppressWarnings worked, but @Suppress("unused") did work.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the above solutions work for me, or rather what they were saying seemed not to apply to my version of Android Studio (3.4.1) running on Windows 10.  Here's what I did to solve this problem of not knowing what string value to supply to  @SuppressWarnings

I ran the "Analyze/Inspect Code..." for the module in question. You'll get an "Inspection Results" window.  Navigate that window until you find the lint warning line that you want suppressed.  Double clicking on the error message will take you to line of code that the warning message applies to.  Right clicking on the error message will give you a drop-down menu, and you'll get an option to suppress the warning on a class, method or parameter basis.  Select the way you want the warning message suppressed.  Navigate to the code and you'll see the @SuppressWarning line that was added. You'll see the actual string parameter passed to the @SuppressWarning line.

If you rerun "Analyze/Inspect Code.." again, that same warning will show up in the "Inspection Result" window, but this time you'll see that the line will also say that it's suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, just click on the deprecated word and press ALT + ENTER on your keyboard,  click on  --> Inspection 'Deprecated API usage' options. In the drop-down menu, u can select the option that matches your choice, e.g Suppress for class, Suppress for method, Suppress for statement.. Hope it helps.