# getNetworkInfo() is deprecated in Android Studio using API 23

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem in my code. I am following a tutorial and it's using an old API.

Here's my code:

```
package com.flax.security;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

        boolean wifi = conman.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if(wifi) {
            tv.setText("This wifi is on!");
        } else {
            tv.setText("The wifi is off!");
        }


    }
}
```

My error says that `getNetworkInfo` is already depracated. How can I resolve this? I am new in Android Development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc for [getNetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(int)) says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 23. This method does not
>   support multiple connected networks of the same type. Use
>   getAllNetworks() and getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network) instead.

So what you could do is check at runtime to see if the API level is high enough to support those two methods, and use those instead of getNetworkInfo.

You are by no means obliged to stop using deprecated APIs.  But it's a good idea to consider stopping.

You can use the IDE to [suppress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603677/supported-suppresswarnings-values-in-android-studio) the warning too if you just don't want to see it.